# Where can I find information on how to control stepper motors with blender?

Tags: add-on, source-code

My goal is to build a robotic arm I can control with blender. I've seen videos showing that blender has the capability to control thing in the real world, so I know this magic can be done. I just can't find a wizard to teach me the spells. :) Any help you can provide in completing my quest would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!

Comment: There is lots of options. I would go with a Raspberry Pi that controls the arm and is fully independent and then setup a script in Blender that relayed the movements via Wifi for the Pi to translate into physical motion. But the Pi is optional if you can write Python to control the arm directly.

Comment: Thank you Rob! I don't have any Python experience so I think the Pi would be my best bet. How do I get Blender to relay the movements? Would hard wire be better than Wifi for accurate quick movements?

Comment: It is very easy to setup client-server with Python so the two act like a web server and web browser. The Client (Blender) sends the commands to the Server (Pi) which is listening and acting. I doubt the Wifi latency would be noticeable.